# Referencing Javascript Object in another object

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to reference Javascript Object that exists inside of another Javascript object?  For instance, taking the data below, how would I properly refer to the "home" of an individual, which is a reference to another object (places) in the same dataset?

```
var data = {
    "people": [{
        "name": "Jack",
        "age": "8",
        "home": data.places[0].country
    }, {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "9",
        "home": data.places[1].country
    }],
    "places": [{
        "country": "Holland"
    }, {
        "country": "Germany"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split up your declaration so that data.places will exist when you reference it.

```
var data = {
    "places": [{
        "country": "Holland"
    }, {
        "country": "Germany"
    }]
}

// data is now defined and has the property "places"

data.people = [{
    "name": "Jack",
    "age": "8",
    "home": data.places[0].country // No more error 
}, {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "9",
    "home": data.places[1].country // No more error either
}]
```

In your question, your object was referencing elements on itself before it had been fully defined. This resulted in a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'places' of undefined`. In my solution, I broke apart your object definition so that when you define `data.people` the `data.places` piece array already exists.

Objects don't have to be declared all at once.

Comment: Mike, thank you this seems to have helped me.  Could you explain a little further what the 'data.people' does?

Comment: @bender Done and done

Answer (score 0):

Generally, JSON is used as a "nested" data format. So, instead of relational pointers to other pieces of data (as in relational databases), the data is simply inserted directly as a sub-object. In practice, this results in some data duplication (denormalization, in database terms).

```
{
    "people": [{
        "name": "Jack",
        "age": "8",
        "home": "Holland"
    }, {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "9",
        "home": "Germany"
    }],
    "places": [{
        "country": "Holland"
    }, {
        "country": "Germany"
    }]
}
```

The closest thing to "references" that I've seen with standard JSON is when it is used in an API (as in [Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)). In this setup, the references are encoded as API URIs that can later be used by client to request the other bits of the dataset.

```
{
    "people": [{
        "name": "Jack",
        "age": "8",
        "home": "/api/v1/place/1/"
    }, {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "9",
        "home": "/api/v1/place/2/"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Since it's not JSON, the OP has probably hand-written this and *does* need normalisation for simple updating. But if would solve the problem, yes, and even would be shorter :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not reformat your data like so:

```
var data.places = {
    "Holland": {otherinfo},
    "Germany": {otherinfo}
};

data.people = [{
        "name": "Jack",
        "age": "8",
        "home": data.places.Holland
    }, {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "9",
        "home": data.places.Germany
    }];
```

Comment: Because that does not work as well?

Comment: @Bergi Fair enough. Edited

Answer (score 0):

I would solve the problem by listing all of the places, assigning each an ID.

Then each person would simply reference the ID.

```
var data = {
    "people": [{
        "name": "Jack",
        "age": "8",
        "home_id": 0
    }, {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "9",
        "home_id": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Inge",
        "age": "11",
        "home_id": 0
    }],
    "places": [{
        "id" : 0,
        "country": "Holland"
    }, {
        "id" : 1,
        "country": "Germany"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, I'm OK with disagreement. But please give an explanation as to WHY you disagree.